# Check if audio playing to stop it

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to reset my audio on typing on the same key I used to play it

HTML :

```
<audio preload="auto" id="sound1" src="sons/nadal.ogg" src="sons/nadal.mp3"></audio>
```

JS :

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){

var son_1 = document.getElementById('sound1');

   if (e.keyCode == 65) { 
     son_1.play();
     son_1.currentTime = 0;
     return false;
   }

});
```

Works perfectly to launch it, but I want to stop it when i type on the same key. I tried lots of solution found on the internet but I don't achieved to make one work.

Thank you very much for your help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to check the property 'paused' to determine if the audio tag is playing or not:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var son_1 = document.getElementById('sound1');
    if(e.keyCode == 65){
        son_1.currentTime = 0;
        if(son_1.paused)
            son_1.play();
        else
            son_1.pause();
        return false;
    }
});
```